# Converting Dictionary Key type in Swift 5 with Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues:)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alamofire, swift5

I am writing an application with networking capabilities for iOS 13.4 (Swift 5, Xcode 11) using Alamofire 5. I have created my custom type `typealias KeyedParameters = [ParameterKeys: Any]` to be able to use my API Parameter Keys in a 'swifty' short way (i.e. `.login` instead of `KeyedParameters.login.rawValue`).

The problem is when I try do convert this type back to default Alamofire's `Parameters`, I receive following error: `Cannot convert return expression of type 'Dictionary<ParameterKeys, Any>' to return type 'Parameters' (aka 'Dictionary<String, Any>')`.

Casting:

```
extension KeyedParameters {
    var parameters: Parameters {
        Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: map { ($0.key.rawValue, $0.value) })
    }
}
```

ParameterKeys:

```
enum ParameterKeys: String {
    // MARK: - Auth and User
    case id, login, password, email, name
    case createdAt = "created_at"
    ...
}
```

How error looks:

[image]

Comment: I have also tried string interpolation ("\($0.key.rawValue)"), explicit constructor call (String($0.key.rawValue)) and force type cast ($0.key.rawValue as! String) — hadn't worked either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd better explicitly highlight type like this:

```
extension KeyedParameters {
    var parameters: Parameters {
        return Parameters(uniqueKeysWithValues:
            self.map { (key, value) in (key.rawValue, value) }
        )
    }
}
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

I think this might be just a case of a bad error message.

Your extension `KeyedParameters` (a `typealias` for `[ParameterKeys: Any]`) is actually equivalent to:

```
extension Dictionary where Key == ParameterKeys, Value: Any { ...
```

Swift has some odd behaviour when calling an initializer for a generic type within the declaration of that type itself. If the generic types are different, it won't handle that properly.

Here's a simpler example without so many red herrings (type aliases, enum raw values, etc.) and dependencies:

```
extension Dictionary  {
    func returnADifferentDict() -> [Character: String] {
        let words = [
            "apple", "anchovies",
            "bacon", "beer",
            "celery"
        ]

        return Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues:
            words.map { ($0.first!, $0) }
        )

//      fixed:
//      return Dictionary<Character, String>(uniqueKeysWithValues:
//          words.map { ($0.first!, $0) }
//      )

    }
}
```

The solution is to explicitly specify the generic type parameters of the generic type you're initializing. In your case,

```
extension KeyedParameters {
    var parameters: Parameters {
        Dictionary<String, Any>(uniqueKeysWithValues: map { ($0.key.rawValue, $0.value) })
    }
}
```

Comment: @Alexander: Would you consider this a bug in the compiler? Seems to me like it should just work, or is this actually a documented limitation of the language?

Comment: @Rengers I'm not sure. I would suggest you ask on the Swift forums